# Stack overflow while using recursive function

Tags: c#, recursion, stack-overflow

I am trying to do a simple coding challenge that requires me to do the following:

You are given n, return an array ans, composed in such way:

```
`ans = [n, n - 5, n - 10, ... , m, m + 5, ... , n - 5, n]`, where m stands for the first non-positive integer obtained by subtractions.
```

Try to solve it without any loop.

Example

For `n = 25`, the output should be

```
listWithoutLoop(n) = [25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25].
```

I have done this code:

```
int[] listWithoutLoop(int n)
{
    List<int> test = new List<int>();

    if (test.Count > 2 && test[test.Count - 1] == n)
        return test.ToArray();

    if (n <= 0)
    {
        test.Add(n + 5);
        return listWithoutLoop(n + 5);
    }
    else
    {
        test.Add(n - 5);
        return listWithoutLoop(n - 5);
    }
}
```

But I keep getting a stack overflow when running it. Is recursion supported by c#? If so, how to prevent getting a stackoverflow exception when running it?

Comment: You keep re-creating `test` in every recursive call so `test.Count > 2` is always false so you never reach the base case.

Comment: StackOverflow in recursion is always because of the same thing: your exit condition is never reached.

Comment: What happens if you move `List<int> test = new List<int>();` **above** `int[] listWithoutLoop(int n)`?

Comment: For the last part : of course C# supports recursion. Did you try your code in any other language ? It should raise the same error.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I moved the list above function and it seems to work fine. But that brings me another question. Is it possible to declare a list without creating it every time I get inside the function? I have to make all code within the function itself for the challenge.

Comment: Make list argument of your function and pass it to every recursive call.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To simplify, I splitted the function to add up and add down separately (it's always better to have simple and understandable code at all times)

```
    static void Main()
    {
        int n = 20;
        int interval = 5;

        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        AddDown(list, n, 0, interval);
        AddUp(list, 0, n, interval);

        int[] arrInt = list.ToArray();

    }

    static void AddDown(List<int> list, int currentNumber, int targetNumber, int interval)
    {
        if(currentNumber > targetNumber)
        {
            list.Add(currentNumber);
            AddDown(list, currentNumber - interval, targetNumber, interval);
        }
    }

    static void AddUp(List<int> list, int currentNumber, int targetNumber, int interval)
    {
        if (currentNumber <= targetNumber)
        {
            list.Add(currentNumber);
            AddUp(list, currentNumber + interval, targetNumber, interval);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define the `test` list above the `listWithoutLoop()` method.

```
List<int> test = new List<int>();
int[] listWithoutLoop(int n)
{
....
}
```